# KDE Connect to Sync Android Device with CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kde, devices, android

What are the KDE Connect process and packages that needed to sync android devices with centOS 7. I want to bridge centOS and android but couldn't find any solution online.

Comment: You need to have nux-desktop-ru repro to ease installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly, but just install `kdeconnect` on your OS plus `sshfs` and bingo you should have it. From there you should be able to access your android device via your kdeconnect app.